# magento upgrade from 1.6.2 to 1.7.0.2 - Will the db base be changed?

Tags: database, magento

i am looking into upgrading my magento community from 1.6.2 to 1.7.0.2.

First i will do this on my test server, but there are some errors during updating in magento connect, so i have to upload some files my self ...

but when i going to put these data into the live environment, can i just simply copy my data from the ftp to the live website?

Or are there also some new/changed settings in the database?

And if yes on the last question, which lines are changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid upload core library changes via ftp.

The fastest and more secure way is to patch your application using the [diff files](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download/diff)

patch -p0 -f < 1.6.2.0-1.7.0.0.diff

Then when you first visit your site Magento will automatically upgrade your db

Comment: thanks for your comment. I will try this. Because the magento connect gives some errors during updating ...

Comment: this may not work for newer versions. in that case you have to apply patch using: patch -p1 -f < xxx.diff

Answer (score 3):

I was able to successfully upgrade Magento from 1.6.1 to 1.7.using Connect Manager.
Here are the steps I had foung and followed

1. Go to yourdomain. com/magento/downloader/ (of course, make this
   match your installation’s path.

   1. Because I had installed Magento using tar.gz package provided with a skin I wanted to use, Magento Connect didn’t have all the
      extensions listed for upgrading. I had to type
      “connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Mage_All_Latest” in the
      “Install New Extensions / Paste extension key to install”
   2. If you run into an error along the lines of “CONNECT ERROR: Package ‘Mage_All_Latest’ is invalid” repeated several times, once
      for each package, it is because the files already exist, and you
      have to remove a line of code in order for it to over-write data.
   3. After everything has updated, you will probably have some errors. Make sure you clean the cache and session directories (delete
      everything in /var/cache and /var/session)
   4. If you receive a “500 Internal Server Error” it is more than likely because of file and folder permissions.  It took .5 sec to
      reset all of the permissions to what they needed to be.
   5. If you receive a “Service Temporarily Unavailable The server is temporarily unable to service your request” error on a Magento
      formatted header, it is probably because the store is set to offline
      mode to prevent visitors from screwing up the installation process.
      To fix this, delete the“maintenance.flag” file found in the root of
      your magento installation directory.
   6. Everything should be ready!

Answer (score 0):

best way to update is get a fresh mage zip 1.7.1 or whatever, and connect it to your current DB.  When you go to index - the new install will update your DB to the latest MAge DB.  This way you dont have to use connect etc.  The mage zip has its own sql updates.

Make sure you put your current theme into the new install etc, and test it 1st on localhost etc.