# Upgrade Magento 1.6.2 to 1.7.0.1

Tags: magento, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [magento upgrade from 1.6.2 to 1.7.0.2 - Will the db base be changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372903/magento-upgrade-from-1-6-2-to-1-7-0-2-will-the-db-base-be-changed)

This is probably very simple for most folks but I'm struggling to upgrade a stable development store running 1.6.2 with no plugins and very few products to the latest version of 1.7.0.1.

When using Magento Connect I select one or several packages to upgrade and everyone gives me an error:

"CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Mage_Downloader 1.7.0.0 conflicts with: community/Mage_All_Latest 1.6.2.0"

Which is understandable as there's already a Magento install there... but I want to upgrade it!

Now, I have searched around and I can't find my specific problem with a fix. Am I missing a simple step here?

Comment: This method works for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163847/magento-upgrade-takes-too-long-and-never-completes

Answer (score 2):

Selecting Mage_All_Latest alone, upgrades all your Magento core installation. So you only need to select that one if you want to upgrade your entire core installation. If you want to install specific core pieces, then select the individual pieces, but NOT the Mage_All_Latest. You don't need both.

In my upgrades to 1.7.0.2 I experiences a few dependency warnings even though I only chose the Mage_All_Latest upgrade. If that occurs you can easily do the individual piece installs as indicated by the warnings you've received.