# Where to write command line in magento upgrade?

Tags: magento, command-line

i want to upgrade magento 1.7.0 to 1.7.2.
[See this link](http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-upgrade-guide/)

But my question is where to enter commandlines? Are they in commandprompt? If so then which path should be set? like from `c:>/` at root or which folder?

In that link line is :
`Next, enter this command:
./mage sync`

So where to write this command?

Answer (score 0):

I did this myself the other day from 1.7.0.0 to 1.7.0.2.  They are not talking about the local command prompt, its the SSH command line.  I would recommend you handle this upgrade by downloading the diff files from the Magento site here;

[Magento diff files](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download/diff)

Upload the two files to the root of your Magento installation ( you will upload the diff file between v 1.7.0.0 and 1.7.0.1 and the diff file between 1.7.0.1 and 1.7.0.2 ).

Then you use the Linux `patch` command to run the diff files from your shell prompt

```
patch -p0 -f < 1.7.0.0-1.7.0.1.diff
```

and then

```
patch -p0 -f < 1.7.0.1-1.7.0.2.diff
```

Here's another SO thread about it - [Upgrading using Diff files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372903/magento-upgrade-from-1-6-2-to-1-7-0-2-will-the-db-base-be-changed)

Comment: but what is this shell prompt? i am new for this

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method domdocument::loadXML() in C:\wamp\www.....\downloader\lib\Mage\Xml\Parser.php on line 111 i am getting this error while clivk on check for updates

Comment: Ah, I see - you are updating a version on a local machine.  Here's a thread on this with an answer by Anton S http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681925/how-to-upgrade-magento-in-local-server

Comment: And here is a link to a Magento forum thread on upgrading on WAMP, the user has installed Cygwin to allow him to use shell commands - http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/248230/#t398701

Comment: manually doing all process manually like Anton says is tedious and errors may be there. can you say what is this error when i click on check_on_upgrades? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520618/upgrade-magento-to-latest-version